# PHP 7.4 under nginx with php-fpm - single shared APCu cache - how?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a PHP 7.4 set of scripts running with APCu extension, which is used by the code as a general object store for all users who visit the single hosted website.  Due to my own lack of understanding, I later found out that the APCu cache is established **per PHP process**.  So what I am seeing is that in some cases **user 'a'** is getting a different cached value than **user 'b'** (presumably since PHP-FPM has forked a new process for user 'b').

But it's still not clear to me exactly how to set up php-fpm so that all incoming requests will be inside of child processes that are derived from the same parent process.

APCu guru krakjoe [said this](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/issues/121) back in 2015 (my emphasis in bold):

> Just to answer the original question ... as @fruitl00p said, you can
> configure your way out of the problem of not being able to share if
> you are using fpm.
>
> There is a difference between using fpm and using fcgi, I should
> probably put in a PR to phptherightway to clear it up.
>
> **The rule is that only child processes can access what their parent
> created**; In FCGI spawned processes are not necessarily a child of
> their parent, they may not be actual forks. If your process manager
> works like conventional FCGI/CGI then you will not be able to share,
> if it works like FPM, and initializes PHP in a parent and forks child
> interpreters then you will have no problem.

Further research led me to php-fpm www.conf file and the settings for:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
```

So - is it as simple as changing this to:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 50
```

i.e. is this the way to force php-fpm to make sure all child processes point back to a single parent?  Thus, assuring that there is only one global APCu cache in play?  I realize that I need to do math to figure out the correct pm.max_children value.

**Please note**: I can't switch to memcached at this point, since I am relying on a regex iteration over the APCu keys via an APCUIterator object.  I may get there eventually, but as of now I have to stick with APCu.

Comment: All PHP-FPM processes are forked by a single parent, and the APCu cache should be shared among them. Please share the full PHP and nginx configuration in your question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thank you for that insight - and now, based on some additional testing I did yesterday, it does seem like all php-fpm PIDs are pointing back to a common parent PID.  I'm using an essentially 'plain vanilla' config for nginx and php.  Also, the real cause of my problem ended up being I am deployed in OpenShift in three pods - so I have three different PHP/caches.  Users hit the pods randomly. 
 Which means I have to move this all to a separate micro-service specifically for caching.

Comment: Or you can route requests based on IP hash so the requests consistently reach the same server.